# Subtracting sums from two tables group by a third table amounts double in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables

```
client,fees,financial
```

I want to

- sum all the fees(fees.fee) for client '925' and subtract any payments(financial.payment).
- show the  client lastname(client.lastname).

The fees and financial tables are FK to client.Id via a fees.clientId and financial.clientId.

I thought this would be simple but individual statements show correct amounts but when joined, they double and triple due to the many fees and one payment.

I have tried many different statements and being new to sql am completely stumped.

Could someone direct me to a sample on point or aid in writing this select statement.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please post some sample data

Comment: sounds like you just need some grouping, but can't help without proper schema and sample data

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

This should get you on the right path. You can run the below code in isolation from your actual database.

```
CREATE TABLE #client 
    ( 
      id INT, 
      name NVARCHAR(10) 
    )

CREATE TABLE #fees
    (
      clientId INT ,
      fees DECIMAL(18, 2)
    )

CREATE TABLE #financials
    (
      clientId INT ,
      payment DECIMAL(18, 2)
    )

INSERT  INTO #client ( id, name )
VALUES  ( 925, N'Company A' )

INSERT  INTO #fees ( clientId , fees )
        SELECT  925 , 120.00
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  925 , 20.00
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  925 , 200.00
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  925 , 60.00

INSERT  INTO #financials ( clientId , payment)
        SELECT  925 , 125
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  925 , 250
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  925 , 75

-- total fees = 400
SELECT  clientId ,
        SUM(fees) Fees
FROM    #fees
GROUP BY clientId

-- total paid = 450
SELECT  clientId ,
        SUM(payment) Paid
FROM    #financials
GROUP BY clientId

-- Single query with difference
SELECT  c.id ,
        c.name ,
        TotalFees ,
        TotalPaid ,
        f.TotalFees - fi.TotalPaid AS FeesLessPaid
FROM    #client c
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT clientId ,
                            SUM(fees) TotalFees
                     FROM   #fees
                     GROUP BY clientId
                   ) f ON f.clientId = c.id
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT clientId ,
                            SUM(payment) TotalPaid
                     FROM   #financials
                     GROUP BY clientId
                   ) fi ON fi.clientId = c.id

DROP TABLE #client
DROP TABLE #fees
DROP TABLE #financials
```

Produces:

```
id  name        TotalFees   TotalPaid   FeesLessPaid
925 Company A   400.00      450.00      -50.00
```

Comment: I prefer left outer client with other table. It will not missout on any clients.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like following:

```
SELECT CO.LASTNAME,COALESCE(A.FEE,0)-COALESCE(B.PAYMENT,0) AMT_LEFT
FROM CLIENT CO
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT C.CLIENTID,SUM(F.FEE)FEE
    FROM CLIENT C
    INNER JOIN FEES F
    ON C.CLIENTID=F.CLIENTID)A
ON CO.CLIENTID=A.CLIENTID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT C.CLIENTID,SUM(F.PAYMENT)PAYMENT
    FROM CLIENT C
    INNER JOIN FINANCIAL F
    ON C.CLIENTID=F.CLIENTID)B
ON CO.CLIENTID=B.CLIENTID
```